# How to take list of order ID from csv file using pandas and pass it in SQL query?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas

i have imported all other necessary packages

```
df = pd.read_csv("orderid", usecols['order ID column'])

stmt = "select **"I WANT ORDER ID TO COME HERE"** from facts.public.customer_interaction_fact;"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your order ID's should be in a the `where` part of the sql query. Assuming the table column is `order_id`. Then you can create the sql query statement as follows:

a) if your order_id column in the database is of **number** type:

```
stmt = "select * from facts.public.customer_interaction_fact where order_id in ({})".format(','.join(map("{}".format, df['order ID column'].values)))
```

b) if your order_id column in the database is of **char** type:

```
stmt = "select * from facts.public.customer_interaction_fact where order_id in ({})".format(','.join("'{}'".format, df['order ID column'].values)))
```

**In any case it's better, however, to use [parametrized queries](https://security.openstack.org/guidelines/dg_parameterize-database-queries.html).**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by embedding the values of your `order_id` column into the SQL statement.

First create a long string with your `order_id` column values, each enclosed in single quotes:

```
order_id_to_grab = ",".join([f"'{s}'" for s in df['order ID column'].values])
```

Then put it in a SQL statement:

```
sql_st = "SELECT * FROM facts.public.customer_interaction_fact where order_id in (" + order_id_to_grab + ")"
```